# url string, jquery/js get numbers that are between two slashes

Tags: jquery, slice

I'm working on a forum that has url's which look like so:

```
http://www.place.com/forum/d7/2/
http://www.place.com/forum/d7/22/
http://www.place.com/forum/d7/234/
http://www.place.com/forum/d7/9999/
http://www.place.com/forum/d7/98765/
```

/d7/ is the username
/2/ is the user ID

The user ID's go from 1 to, let's say unlimited.

How do I 'get' the user ID?

I figured out how to get it if it's only one number, e.g., 2. But how do I tell it to look at every number that is between the last two slashes?

Comment: link us some code you wrote, and we will adjust it. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get you the answer you seek.

```
var url = "http://www.place.com/forum/d7/9999/".split("/");
var id = url[url.length - 2];
```

this will work if there is a trailing `/`.

If there is not, then it is `-1` instead of `-2`, but if you check the last character, you can use that as your understanding.

```
var url = "http://www.place.com/forum/d7/9999/";
var isLastSlash = (url[url.length -1]=="/")? true: false;
var url= url.split("/");
var id = url[url.length - (isLastSlash? 2: 1)];
return id;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. You also taught me something unintended about how to 'think about' working with strings, so thanks for that, too. :)

Comment: No problem! :)  Im glad i could help.  I also wanted to write the alternate incase the url doesnt have the trailing slash (`/`), or it is optional and could be there (or not).  Dont forget to label the answer as found on whichever answer you choose is correct.  That way future coders will see it.

Comment: Oh +1 for handling the no trailing slash case =]

Comment: @Fallenreaper throw what was done here into a function so you can use it anytime you need to, you can modify said function as you wish to make it reusable anytime. My two cents.

Comment: No need using ternary operator or parenthesis, replace line with:

var isLastSlash = url[url.length -1]==="/";

Comment: @NielsVermeiren Correcy, though i wanted to show it was clearly a boolean

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is this:

```
var result, str = "http://www.place.com/forum/d7/98765/";
var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf('/');
if (str.slice(-1) != "/") {
    result = str.substring(lastIndex + 1, str.length);
}
else {
    var prevIndex = str.lastIndexOf('/', lastIndex - 1);
    result = str.substring(prevIndex + 1, lastIndex);
}
```

Find the last index of `/` and the second last then find the substring, if no trailing `/` just find everything after.

EDIT: Added solution for no trailing `/` as I was inspired by @Fallenreaper

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uzxcodu1/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression:

```
/^.*/(\d+)/$/mg
```

Example code:

```js
var url="http://www.place.com/forum/d7/98765/"
var re = /^.*\/(\d+)\/$/mg;
var id= re.exec(url)[1]
alert(id);
```

(there are other, perhaps better, methods to use with regexs)